# MYSQL - date_add(datex, interval cpt day)

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is to set the value cpt in the statement

```
DATE_ADD(firstqDate, INTERVAL @val DAY )
```

to get each sweep of loop a new date.

This statement is a line from a stored procedure which 2 values depending on a date and the date before.

Here is the stored procedure :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updating_all_qch; 

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updating_all_qCh() 
BEGIN

DECLARE firstqDate,date2 date;
DECLARE p, c float;
DECLARE cpt, val int;
set val = 0;
select count(*) into cpt from quotes;
SET @firstqDate = (select qDate from quotes ORDER BY YEAR(qDate) ASC, MONTH(qDate) ASC, DAY(qDate) ASC limit 1,1);
WHILE val <= cpt DO
SET date2 = (select qDate from quotes where qDate like DATE_ADD(firstqDate, INTERVAL @val DAY );
SET p = (select qOp from quotes where qDate date2
SET c = (select qCl from quotes where qDate like DATE_SUB(date2, INTERVAL 1 DAY));
update quotes
set qCh = (p * (100/c) ) / 100;
set val = val + 1;
end while;
END$$
```

I do not know why but mysql raises an error at line 11.

My question : is there a way to set a cpt in the value interval of the function date_add to get something like

```
val = 0 >>> DATE_SUB(date2, INTERVAL 0 DAY)
val = 1 >>> DATE_SUB(date2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Date function in front of DATE)ADD as follows,
SET date2 = (select qDate from quotes where qDate like date(DATE_ADD(firstqDate, INTERVAL @val DAY));